# Send Connector to send emails through VPN to another exchange server

Tags: exchange

We are trying to send emails to one of our exchange server which is not part of the domain but we have a VPN tunnel in between.

The idea is to create a dedicated send/receive connector to send/receive emails between this two exchange server.

I was looking into this article [Create a Send connector to route outbound mail through a smart host](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/connectors/outbound-smart-host-routing?view=exchserver-2019) but not sure what to use as smart host for this case.

The reason we are trying this is because we are having issue with our spam filter to send/receive emails in between us as its seeing the other domain as external sender and causing issues.

We have two way domain trust in between both domains as well. Can someone help me out pointing what can we do in this scenario.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any reason why you would not create an IP exception in the spam filter for the remote server? Where does the spam filter sit in the network? Is it external or software running on the exchange server?

Comment: We use an external spam service where we cant add an exception unfortunately as we use the spam service as our email career as well. We use them as smart host for both side. Plus we use a domain spoofing service from the same service where it marks any external sender sending emails using our domain as spoofed email as it seeing the second exchange server as external system. The system isnt very smart tbh. They suggested us to use a dedicated send connector to send emails between this two domain directly somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with joe, it is simple way to solve your issue is to add IP exception in the spam filter. According to your description, you issue related to spam filter rather than send connector.

In addition, smart host delivery involves specifying the IP address or hostname of the Exchange server to send a message to another system (usually an email security device or cloud service), which is then responsible for further delivery of the email.

Comment: We use an external spam service where we cant add an exception unfortunately as we use the spam service as our email career as well. We use them as smart host for both side. Plus we use a domain spoofing service from the same service where it marks any external sender sending emails using our domain as spoofed email as it seeing the second exchange server as external system. The system isnt very smart tbh. They suggested us to use a dedicated send connector to send emails between this two domain directly somehow.

Comment: What is the version of your exchange?

Answer (score 0):

Since we had a s2s vpn tunnel and trust between both domain I just created a dedicated send connector on both exchange and used local IP of other exchange on each side and now all emails are going through the vpn tunnel and not looking for public mx record hence no more issue with spam filter.